# Stored procedure execution take too many times

Tags: sql, sql-server

The stored procedure is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spManagedRouteSheetList]
@dStartDate DateTime,
@dEndDate DateTime
AS
BEGIN 
SELECT IT.TriggerParentID,IT.ProductID, IT.[Weight],IT.[DateTime],IT.ProductType,IT.InOutType,IT.TriggerParentType FROM ITransaction IT 
    WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate

    --YarnCategory 
    SELECT YarnCategoryID,Name,Code FROM YarnCategory WHERE YarnCategoryID IN (SELECT Distinct ProductID FROm ITransaction IT WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate) 

    --RouteSheet 
    SELECT RouteSheetID,RoutesheetNo, ReqYarnQty, [date],RSState,Shift,Subfactory,(SELECT Name FROM Location WHERE LocationID=Subfactory) 
    FROM Routesheet where RoutesheetID IN (SELECT distinct IT.TriggerParentID FROM ITransaction IT WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate)

    --RSInQCDetail
    SELECT RouteSheetID,Qty,YarnFormat,ManagedLotID FROM RSInQCDetail WHERE RouteSheetID IN     (SELECT distinct IT.TriggerParentID FROM ITransaction IT WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate)


    --RouteSheet History
    SELECT RouteSheetID,YarnQtyInLBS,[Event] from RouteSheetHistoryEnhance WHERE EVENt IN (14) 
    AND RouteSheetID IN (SELECT distinct IT.TriggerParentID FROM ITransaction IT WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in 
    (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate)

END
```

Execute procedure:

```
EXECUTE dbo.[spManagedRouteSheetList] '21 May 2012 08:00:00','22 May 2012 08:00:00'..
```

It will take 2 mis but if I execute the following query it takes only 1 or 3 seconds

```
DECLARE @dStartDate as datetime
        ,@dEndDate as datetime

        SET @dStartDate='21 May 2012 08:00:00'
        SET @dEndDate='22 May 2012 08:00:00'


SELECT IT.TriggerParentID,IT.ProductID, IT.[Weight],IT.[DateTime],IT.ProductType,IT.InOutType,IT.TriggerParentType FROM ITransaction IT 
    WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate

    --YarnCategory 
    SELECT YarnCategoryID,Name,Code FROM YarnCategory WHERE YarnCategoryID IN (SELECT Distinct ProductID FROm ITransaction IT WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate) 

    --RouteSheet 
    SELECT RouteSheetID,RoutesheetNo, ReqYarnQty, [date],RSState,Shift,Subfactory,(SELECT Name FROM Location WHERE LocationID=Subfactory) 
    FROM Routesheet where RoutesheetID IN (SELECT distinct IT.TriggerParentID FROM ITransaction IT WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate)

    --RSInQCDetail
    SELECT RouteSheetID,Qty,YarnFormat,ManagedLotID FROM RSInQCDetail WHERE RouteSheetID IN     (SELECT distinct IT.TriggerParentID FROM ITransaction IT WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate)


    --RouteSheet History
    SELECT RouteSheetID,YarnQtyInLBS,[Event] from RouteSheetHistoryEnhance WHERE EVENt IN (14) 
    AND RouteSheetID IN (SELECT distinct IT.TriggerParentID FROM ITransaction IT WHERE IT.InOutType=101 and IT.LotID in ``
    (select ManagedLotID from RSInQCDetail where YarnFormat <>4 and ManagedLotID>0) 
    AND IT.[DateTime]>=@dStartDate AND IT.[DateTime]<@dEndDate)
```

So.. what is the problem with the stored procedure ?

Comment: What does the execution plan say?

Comment: Which database is this for? (postgres, mysql, etc - please add appropriate tag)

Comment: Parameter sniffing? Take a look at; http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 0):

If this is for SQL Server...

This is not necessarily a perfect solution but it may well eliminate the difference you see.

Try adding `WITH RECOMPILE` to the stored procedure definition.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spManagedRouteSheetList]
    @dStartDate DateTime,
    @dEndDate DateTime
WITH RECOMPILE
AS ...
```

Comment: I tried to add "WITH RECOMPILE" to the store procedure definition, but not worked.

Comment: @Md.MasudIqbal Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: @Md.MasudIqbal So when you say it hasn't worked, do you mean that there was an error message (if so, please tell us what that message was) or that there's no error and the performance difference remains?

Comment: Actually there is no error but take times for 2 mins to execute. that is same as before.